# Может ли таблица обтекать картинку?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, таблицы

На сайте есть таблица и справа от нее — картинка, вместе они занимают 100% ширины блока. Нужно, чтобы таблица обтекала картинку внизу, принимая L-образную форму, как это умеет делать обычный текстовый блок. Иными словами, ячейки крайнего правого столбца под картинкой должны быть шире, чем ячейки *этого же столбца* рядом с картинкой.

```
|    ДАТА    |         ОПИСАНИЕ        |  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
| 30.04.2020 | Информация в таблице    |  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
|            | регулярно обновляется.  |  %% КАРТИНКА %%
| 29.04.2020 | Ширина столбца «Дата»   |  % не зависит %
|            | минимальна и неизменна. |  % от таблицы %
| 28.04.2020 | Ширина ячеек столбца    |  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
|            | «Описание» неодинакова  |  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
|            | и зависит от положения. |
| 27.04.2020 | Ячейки столбца «Описание», расположенные |
|            | под картинкой, должны растягиваться,     |
|            | занимая всю доступную ширину блока.      |
| 25.04.2020 | Возможно ли создание подобной L-образной |
|            | таблицы средствами HTML и CSS?           |
```

P.S. Отвечая @Neolot, подумал, что и впрямь ни к чему тут таблицу городить, можно отступами в параграфах все настроить прекрасно, обрамив дату спаном:

```
p {  
    text-indent: -6em;  
    margin-left: 6em;  
}  

p span:first-child {  
    display: inline-block;  
    margin-left: 6em;  
}
```

P.P.S. Если у вас все-таки есть идеи, как сделать L-образную таблицу (и возможно ли это в принципе), поделитесь, пожалуйста. У меня уже чисто академический интерес.

Comment: Поясните, какой смысл этой затеи? Зачем так делать?

Comment: @Neolot Для единообразия. На остальных страницах сайта параграфы текста точно так же обтекают такого же размера картинку. Таблица без границ (я их изобразил для наглядности), так что по сути это те же параграфы, только с выноской даты. Проще всего, конечно, вместо строк таблицы сделать параграфы с отрицательным отступом первой строки, но поскольку ширина разных дат неодинакова (например, 11.11.2019 и 20.02.2020), начало описания будет прыгать в каждой новости, а это довольно неряшливо выглядит.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Границ вообще не нужно, а между ячейками пусть будет отступ 1em, например, это несущественно. Интересует именно алгоритм обтекания рисунка.

Comment: А почему нельзя было добавить картинку в ячейку таблицы?)

Comment: @Optimus-Prime Потому что таблица регулярно дополняется, прежние строки сдвигаются вниз, и высота каждой зависит от объема текста. Но даже если бы содержимое таблицы было неизменным, ее пропорции все равно динамически изменяются при изменении ширины блока, и я при всем желании не смог бы подобрать «оптимальное» количество строк для картинки так, чтобы гарантированно создать эффект обтекания на всех устройствах.